# TypeError: unbound method

Tags: class, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm writing a program that converts numbers from one basis to another through different methods and I'm working with classes and modules.

Module #1 contains the class Number with attributes value and basis
Module #2 contains the class Controller with no attributes
Module #3 contains the class Console with attribute ctrl

```
class Console:
     def __init__(self, ctrl):
         self.__ctrl = ctrl

     def __successiveDivisions(self):
         n1 = self.__readNo("Enter the number: ")
         b1 = self.__readBase("Enter the base of the number: ")
         b2 = self.__readBase("Enter the base in which to convert the number: ")
         n2 = self.__ctrl.successiveDivisions(n1, b1, b2)
```

*self.__ctrl.successiveDivisions(n1,b1,b2)* returns an object of type number

Why do I get this error?

```
   TypeError: unbound method successiveDivisions() must be called with Controller instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

I tried writing:

```
  n2 = Console()
  n2 = self.__ctrl.successiveDivisions(n1, b1, b2)
```

But I got this error:

```
 TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
 n2 = Console()
```

You need to pass a parameter as you have declared in class definition. That is why you are getting

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

It should be

```
n2 = Console(ctrl)
```

Where `ctrl` should support `successiveDivisions(n1, b1, b2)`. Means it should support `successiveDivisions` with three arguments. This should not be recursive which would be infinite.

Comment: Well, that's the problem... successiveDivisions is recursive.
And if I write n=Console(ctrl) I get the first error again. What changes should I make to get it working?